# How to excluded the full json file content while make a InvokeHTPP on Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi, data-ingestion

I am making a flowfile which is getting the data from a public API then I splits the data in order to have one record for each message then convert each message to CSV then update the filename by giving a UUID. Then I am putting the file on my local disk.

The flowfile work but I am getting in my local disk directory the file containing all the messages (data) and I do not want to get this file but just the unique file with one message per file.

How do I exclude the original file containing all the data ?

I am supposed to get 100 file in my repository after the execution of a flowfile but I am gettin 101 (including the file which I don't want).

[image]

I tried using RouteAttribute processor without success.

Comment: after splitjson you are passing "original" to a next processor. just terminate the "original" after splitjson.

Comment: Could you explain why you would need to get all the relationships to be sent to a processor ? Its always best to just pass on the data that you really need to the next processing task, and also what does the wait processor here used for. You can simplify your flow by just having the right relationships and removing the redundant processors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nolan

Few things to unpack here:

1. Split, then convert is anti pattern.  Investigate RecordReader based processors.  You can do split/convery in a single processor.
2. Do not use wait, unless you have thoroughly tested and understood how it works.
3. As Datawranger and Daggett suggest,  do not route all relationships to your downstream processor.  Only the correct, success relationship should be pointed downstream.  During testing, I always route all relationships to an output port to evaluate those results as needed in flow developement.

The final answer, delete your multi route line from SplitJson to ConvertRecord. Remake a single new line for splits.  Auto terminate original.  Route failure to output port during testing.   Investigate alternative routes for failure (or auto terminate) once you have flow working.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I've been able to resolve it by correcting the connections and to get only the wanted files in my output directory.
The Wait processor was only there to help me checking the content of the queue.
Do correct me if I am wrong by "terminating" the original in the splitJSON processor we are excluding the original file on which the JSON splits are done ?
Any good resources/ books regarding "learning Nifi ingestion" ?

Comment: Find NiFi For Dummies: https://www.cloudera.com/campaign/apache-nifi-for-dummies.html
Also check out Mark's youtube channel:  https://www.youtube.com/@nifinotes5127